# Place Equipment From Ribbon Revit 2015: Transaction already started

Tags: vb.net, transactions, revit

Stack,

I'm programming an external application that works in Autodesk's Revit (2015).  I've created a button on the ribbon that allows the user to place a special equipment that I'll use later to read and pass on to another process.  I using 'TheBuildingCoder's' 'Family API' examples to do so.  The button on the ribbon has an external command set in the .addin file in the ProgramData Directory...

```
<AddIn Type="Command">
    <Assembly>C:\GSN Programs\MyDll.dll</Assembly>
    <AddInId>{97715E4F-EA48-4690-8C62-B5D4836FF452}</AddInId>
    <FullClassName>RcarsPlugIn.PlaceEquipment</FullClassName>
    <VendorId>MyCompany, LLC</VendorId>
    <Text>Place Equipment</Text>
    <VisibilityMode>AlwaysVisible</VisibilityMode>
    <Discipline>Any</Discipline>
    <LanguageType>Unknown</LanguageType>
</AddIn>
```

On the button press, I put the command data into a global variable to use throughout the program...

```
 If IsNothing(gv_oGo) Then
        gv_oGo = New clsGeneralOperations
        gv_oGo.CachedCommandData = exCommandData
        gv_oGo.UiApp = exCommandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Application
 End If
```

With the CommandData cached I move to place the equipment by user pick...

```
 uiDoc = gv_oGo.UiApp.ActiveUIDocument

 oSym = oRF.FindElement(doc, GetType(FamilySymbol), "MyEQUIP")
 uiDoc.PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement(oSym)

Public Function FindElement(doc As Document, targetType As Type, sTargetName As String) As Element
    Return New FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(targetType).FirstOrDefault(Function(e) e.Name.Equals(sTargetName))
End Function
```

That's where the problem comes into play.  I get an error message sent back from Revit stating that "Placement is not permitted in an already modifiable document.  The active transaction must be closed first."  The problem is, I haven't started a different transaction.  The button onthe ribbon is the first that touched when Revit starts.

Is there a way to loop through the open transactions and find one that is open?  Is the document in some state that I don't understand?  I'm not sure which direction to turn here... any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Runnin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, one clarifying question - the exception is occurring on 
`uiDoc.PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement(oSym)` line correct? if so, try using a subtransaction to complete your command instead:

```
        Document doc = uiDoc.Document;

        using (SubTransaction subtr_fam = new SubTransaction(doc))
        {
            try
            {
                uiDoc.PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement(oSym);
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: I struggled with that one for quite a bit, thanks for tuning in and saying something.  I should have posted the answer to my own question, thank you for doing so for me.  The sub-transaction was exactly what I needed to know.  Thank you again.